# Determine image offset

Tags: math, canvas, kineticjs

I've got a large circle with an image as a fill pattern. The circle is rotated.

When I click inside the circle I wish to create a smaller circle which contains the same image and the same offset. Essentially it should look as if the smaller circle is transparent.

So my question is as follows:

How do I determine the offset for the background image of the smaller circle with the rotation of the bigger circle?

Here's an example of the incorrect offset:

[image: An example of the wrong offset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m guessing the source image for your smaller circle is the same as the big circle--just unrotated.

If that’s the case, you need to **find your un-rotated mouseclick position.**

Then you can clip your smaller circle around the unrotated mouseclick and rotate it into place.

Given:

- Your original center of rotation is cx/cy,
- Your angle of rotation is radAngle (in radians)
- Your rotated mousclick point is rx/ry.

You can calculate your un-rotated mouseclick position ( preRX / preRY ) like this:

```
// the bigger circle's rotation point  
var cx=150;
var cy=150;

// the rotation angle in radians
var radAngle=Math.PI/6;   // 30 degrees, for example

// the rotated mouseclick point
var rx=225;
var ry=245;

// the radius of the smaller circle
var smallRadius=50;

// calculate the unrotated mouseclick point
var dx= rx-cx;
var dy= ry-cy;
var preRX= cx+ dx*Math.cos(-radAngle) - dy*Math.sin(-radAngle); 
var preRY= cy+ dy*Math.cos(-radAngle) + dx*Math.sin(-radAngle);
```

Then you make a clipping path using your smaller circle

```
// create a clipping path for the small circle
ctx.arc(preRX,preRY,smallRadius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
```

And finally translate + rotate and draw the clipped image into position

```
// rotate the small circle into position
ctx.translate(cx,cy);
ctx.rotate(radAngle);
ctx.globalAlpha=1.0;
ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YAt5r/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        draw();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";


    function draw(){

        // the bigger circle's rotation point  
        var cx=150;
        var cy=150;

        // the rotation angle in radians
        var radAngle=Math.PI/6;   // 30 degrees

        // the rotated mouseclick point
        var rx=225;
        var ry=245;

        // the radius of the smaller circle
        var smallRadius=50;

        // calculate the unrotated mouseclick point
        var dx= rx-cx;
        var dy= ry-cy;
        var preRX= cx+ dx*Math.cos(-radAngle) - dy*Math.sin(-radAngle); 
        var preRY= cy+ dy*Math.cos(-radAngle) + dx*Math.sin(-radAngle);

        // test

        // rotate the original image and draw it
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(radAngle);
        ctx.globalAlpha=.25;
        ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
        ctx.restore();

        // clip the smaller image, rotate it and draw it
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();

        // create a clipping path for the small circle
        ctx.arc(preRX,preRY,smallRadius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        // rotate the small circle into position
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(radAngle);
        ctx.globalAlpha=1.0;
        ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);

        // stroke the circle
        ctx.arc(preRX,preRY,smallRadius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();

    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Original image is 25% opacity</p>
    <p>Clipped overlay image is 100% opacity</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```